# Is it possible to get VM guest ip in Nat network virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am having virtualbox VM in which Guest addition is install i can get VM ip by below command

```
VBoxManage guestproperty get "vm-name" "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"
```

But, I want to get guest IP in Nat Network without accessing VM, i have created Nat network using below command

```
“VBoxManage natnetwork add -t <nat name> -n "192.168.15.0/24" -e”
```

I attached nat network to VM and Now i want to get guest IP without using guestproperty
I think it is possible because natNetwork i am creating is on physical machine and it works somewhat like DHCP to all VMs. So, virtualbox must be maintaining some information about which ip is assign to which VM for natNetwork.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use nmap like this. You may first need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Then, you can find your VM, if it's running and online:

```
nmap 192.168.15.1-254
```

It should show up in the results.

Comment: If i am having two VMs then how could i know which VM has which ip?@Kalle Elmer

Comment: Well, if the two VMs are configured differently then that would be possible. The scan above will list the port numbers that the VMs listen on and this information could be used to distinguish between them. What are the VMs used for? Why can't you access them directly?

Comment: I am having having two VMs which are in One NAT network , my two VMs contain backup of machines and i am restoring those backups on same virtualbox. Now the problem is i does restore and creates VM but it should go in same NAT network of two VMs and i done that, But it is not possible that my backup machine has guest addition , so i am finding other way to do that, I can't access VMs directly because i want to add port forwarding rules in VM through Perl script for which i need IP in NAT network , i Can't use Nat. @Kalle Elmer

Comment: What if you stop one VM and do the nmap scan? After you have obtained the IP address of the first VM, you can restart the other one.